# If you want (it) - won't mind (it/that)

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

***Would you like an ice cream? Well, you can have one if you want (it). I'm sure Mommy won't mind (it/that).***

Is this perfectly natural without including "it" or "that" in the two last sentences?

Comment: In your context, the first bracketed ***it*** is entirely optional (with or without, both versions are fine). But ***it*** is non-idiomatic for the *second* occurrence - and we wouldn't normally include ***that*** unless we wanted to imply something along the lines of *she won't mind **that**, but there are certainly some other possibilities that **would** bother her*. OR you could quite naturally include ***that*** if preceding text had mentioned something else that the child *can't* have or do because Mommy wouldn't like it.

Answer (score 2):

> Would you like an ice cream?

> Well, you can have one if you want (it).

Dropping the *it* would be fine here. I would often replace it with

> Well, you can have one if you want to

Discussion in comments reveals various opinions about just exactly what repeated text can be omitted here. The long form would have been "Well, you can have one if you want to have one" and some versions drop "to have one" whereas my suggestion drops "have one". This may well shade into differences in style and dialect rather than strict grammatical rules and depends on what the text which it is proposed to drop is.

For the second example

> I'm sure Mommy won't mind (it/that).

In this case it would actually sound more natural if you did drop *it/that*

Comment: Are you a native Anglophone? I don't find ***You can have one if you want to*** at all idiomatic. Obviously it *can* be parsed as *...if you want **to have it***, but it wouldn't be syntactically valid to omit the actual object there *(**it**)* and just keep the verb - *You can have one **if you want to have*** is nonsense. Explicitly including just the infinitive marker *(**to**)* doesn't work for me if the relevant verb is one that *requires* an object, as is the case here.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I often use phrases like "If you really want to" where it is understood what would follow in a complete sentence. So in this case it would be short for "you can have one if you want to have one" which seems complete to me but obviously the repetition of have one sounds awkward hence the fact that I would drop it.

Comment: That's my point. If there ***is*** an object, either drop everything after ***want***, or include it all. If there is no object, as in *You can **go** if you want*, I have no opinion on whether to include the infinitive marker when "deleting" the main verb *(**go**)*. To me it's not really acceptable to include ***to*** without the rest of the verb plus the object in the present context, but I guess if you're a native speaker and you say things like that, I can hardly claim you *don't!* :) So I'll cancel my downvote, but I can't bring myself to actually *upvote*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think “If you want to” is OK as a response, i.e. “Can I turn on the news?”/“Go ahead If you want to.” but I wouldn’t use it in “Do you want to turn on the news? You can if you want, I don’t mind.” I’m not exactly sure why though.

Comment: @ColleenV: For myself, I don't think it matters whether the "reduced" response actually *ends* the utterance or not (if that's what you're getting at). It's just that I'm not at all keen  on including just ***to*** if the "deleted" verb that would in theory come next is actually ***transitive*** (in this case, *...if you want **to have it*** or *...if you want **it*** are both fine, but not *...if you want **to***).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica That makes sense. I don’t think it being at the end was the thing that saved it for me - it was probably the nature of what was left off. “Can I? If you want to.” but “Can I have your old one? If you want it.”

Comment: @ColleenV: Yes! That's exactly it! Sorry for "camping out" on your turf like this, mdewey, but I do find this one quite intriguing. It seems that different people can have different ideas about exactly ***what*** "predictably repeated text" can reasonably be "deleted". For me, *Can I **have** your old one? If you want **to*** doesn't work - but curiously, I find that I'm perfectly happy with *Can I **sell** your old one? If you want **to***.  I’m not exactly sure why though!

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I have edited in some text to try to reflect the variety of views which have been expressed in comments. This all looks more complex than I at first thought.

Comment: @mdewey I think you will find that a surprising number of seemingly simple questions on ELL turn out to be more complex than expected :)